# What is the equivalent AWS cloudformation's json "Ref" in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Given the following Cloudformation JSON:

```
"MyServer" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::EIP",
  "Properties" : {
    "InstanceId" : { "Ref" : "LinuxServer" }
  }
},
```

For eample in Java CDK classes the attribute `InstanceId` in `software.amazon.awscdk.services.ec2.CfnEIP` is a String, but in Cloudformation JSON it can be either a string or an object (which has the "Ref" attribute)

How can i pass the Ref object (or any other type) to the `CfnEIP` class (or any other classes that also support the "Ref" attribute) instead of the String that this class requires?

**EDIT**

I've found out that all the classes that inherits from `CfnRefElement`, have a method `getRef()` which returns a String and behind the scene being converted from a string to an object:

From `"InstanceId" : "notWorkingRef"}` (Java String attribute) to `"InstanceId" : { "Ref" : "someRef" }`.

But there are Cfn classes (e.g. CfnParameter (core lib)) that doesn't inherits from `CfnRefElement` but from `CfnElement` and those once doesn't have the `getRef()` method - how to get the same result with those once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **CfnParameter** construct is a generalization of Cloudformation Parameters in general, and is not itself a specific parameter. It is an element of a cfn construct, therefore inherits CfnElement.
The **CfnRefElement** class exists to allow for the creation of non-resource, referenceable, individual Cloudformation constructs. It is less specific than the CfnResource and extends CfnElement, just as CfnParameter does.
CfnParameter does not contain a .ref element because it is a lower-level generalization then would require one.

Was originally answered on [Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4453)